# Why is the remove() function in my program not working as intended?

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a contact management program in Python 3.6 for my job and I am trying to add a function that will allow the user to delete an individual contact of their choosing within a list.

However, when I run the program, it does not delete the desired list item. Instead it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/cmanagerMain.py", line 10, in <module>
        deleteContact()
    File "C:\Users\cmanagerFunctions.py", line 23, in deleteContact
        contactList.remove(item)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I am still a bit new to Python and as a result am unable to identify where I went wrong.

I would like for someone to identify my error so I can learn from it and also suggest a solution.

Here is the code:

```
contactList = []


class Contact:
    name = ""
    number = ""


def addContact():
    print()
    contact = Contact()
    contact.name = input("Enter contact name: ")
    contact.number = input("Enter contact number: ")
    contactList.append(contact)
    print("Contact added.")
    print()

def deleteContact():
    print()
    item = Contact()
    item.name = input("Enter contact to be deleted: ")
    item.number = input("Enter the number of contact: ")
    contactList.remove(item)
    print()

def getMenuChoice():
    print("1. Add new contact")
    print("2. Print all contacts")
    print("3. Delete a contact")
    print("4. Quit")
    return input("Please enter your choice (1-4): ")


def printContacts():
    print()
    print("Printing contacts...")
    for itm in contactList:
        print(itm.name + "," + itm.number)
    print()


while True:
   choice = getMenuChoice()
   if choice == "1":
       addContact()
   elif choice == "2":
       printContacts()
   elif choice == "3":
       deleteContact()
   elif choice == "4":
       print("Goodbye")
   else:
       continue
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove an element from a list you pass in the item number (zero-based), not the item itself.